# Updating a RecyclerView by a new LiveData<List> return from Room dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I have a conventional Room->DAO->Livedata->Repositiry->ViewModel->RecyclerView app. Different buttons of UI must pass different lists of data to RecyclerView.
By button click I want:

1. Make new @Query in DAO and get new LiveData<`List> object in return.
2. Put this new data into the RecyclerViewAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged () to make new List visuals.

The Dao @Query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entry_table WHERE path LIKE :path ORDER BY priority DESC")
LiveData<List<Entry>> getNotesOfFolder(String path);    //Returns LiveData with List of Entries
```

The recyclerView is updated via onChanged of Observer like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {…
Observer<List<Entry>> entryObserver = new Observer<List<Entry>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Entry> entries) {
        recyclerAdapter.setEntries(entries);
    }
};
```

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.EntryHolder> {…
public void setEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
    this.entries = entries; //setting LiveData content to adapter's List (i.e. entries)
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is that my Observer does not call the onChange method when LiveData receives new value from DAO. I believe it is because this LiveData’s content is not CHANGED but REPLACED by another LiveData.

I tried to re-subscribe the Observer to LiveData again and it somewhat worked, but when I try to call some conventional Room queries like @Delete, I got multiple (up to 10!) onChange calls and some of them behave weirdly and pass the wrong List to RVadapter.

So there two questions:

1. How can I just call onChanged() of my Observer?
2. Is there some other stylish way of passing new LiveData object to RecyclerView dynamically?

Comment: I want you to advice to set `refresh` feature in your page. For example add `SwipeRefreshLayout` to your layout. I think this may be useful to get updated data.

Answer (score 0):

1)

In `viewModel` , create a getter method for live data:

```
//...

private LiveData<List<Entry>> liveData;

//...

public LiveData<List<Entry>> getLiveData() {
    return liveData;
}
```

in `Activity`:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      //...

      viewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Entry>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(List<Entry> entryList) {
              //set new value here
          }
      });

  }
```

2) `DiffUtil` is very helpful to update your list in recycler view and it gives you some nice animations.

Comment: You just described simpliest case of using LiveData. I already  know  this all. It is not what I am asking about.  Problem is that Observer does not trigger on new value of LiveData until i subscribe it to LiveData again.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to re-subscribe the Observer to LiveData again and it somewhat worked, but when I try to call some conventional Room queries like @Delete, I got multiple (up to 10!) onChange calls and some of them behave weirdly and pass the wrong List to RVadapter.

This would make sense if you didn't first *unsubscribe* your observer from the *old* LiveData object... the one you replace when your query changes.

If your query updates, you will need to get a new LiveData from the DAO. If you overwrite your old LiveData with the new one, you will not only need to (re-)subscribe your Observer to the new one, you will also need to unsubscribe it from the old one. Otherwise it will live on and keep updating the observer.